# Could not convert string to float with pandas series in Python

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

```
lat=[]
lon=[]
with open("Rawcomdata.log") as fin: # Input file
    for line in fin:
        if '$GPRMC' in line: # check message from input line
           data=line.split(',')
           lat.append(data[1])  # extract data and store in buffer
           lon.append(data[3])

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df=pd.DataFrame({'lat':lat})
df['lat']=pd.to_numeric(df['lat'], errors='coerce')
df['lat'].fillna(0,inplace=True)
df.to_csv('test.csv')
```

## Objective

How to convert list to dataframe with different header when list is string series format

# Input

```
$GPRMC,134101.25,A,1256.99918,N,07738.00030,E,0.008,159.76,070316,,,A,V*1A
    $GPGSA,A,3,01,02,07,08,10,31,13,30,26,28,,,1.64,0.77,1.44,1*1D
    $GPRMC,,V,,,,,,,,,,N,V*29
    ....................
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of `lat` and `lon`?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously some of your lines don't have valid `float` data, specifically some line have text `lat` which can't be converted to **float**.

For removing `NaN` lines you can use [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) method.

```
df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')
```

Another method without `drop`.

```
df = df[np.isfinite(df['lat'])]
```

Also, you can read your file using `read_csv` function.

```
df = pd.read_csv('Rawcomdata.csv')
```

Comment: @ Mihai Alexandru-Ionut ,Yes I have observed some of the rows of my huge file containes ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, value meaning no data. How to convert this to Nan and finally to zero.

Comment: @Poka, since there is no data, removing these lines can be one option ?

Comment: @ Mihai Alexandru-Ionut It is giving error "could not convert string to float: ". So I have facing two  challenge, how to extract the data(after converting missing data to 0) and finally create a dataframe. Is it possible ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a second solution. Have you tried it ?

Comment: After this line : `df = df.dropna(axis=0, how='all')`, do you see another `NaN` values in your dataset ?

Comment: Use simply `df = df.dropna()`

Comment: Or using notnull method : `df = df[pd.notnull(df['lat'])]`

Comment: For reading from csv you can just use `read_csv` method as in my answer.

Comment: Input file was text file as a tool generate it and the all messages are line by line . Saved the output latitude value to csv file to check the output data.

Comment: @Poka, I think the problem in reading your txt file could be some spaces in your data. You can prevent this using `trim` feature.

Comment: @ Mihai Alexandru-Ionut .Thanks for all your suggestions. I will go through it . Something is wrong in my file do not know.

Comment: It worked with above solution ! I took google help on stack overflow